# Error trying use Action.Send in android action bar

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-actionbar

I tried to set up a share button in android studio. When I click the share button on the action bar, nothing happens. Here is what it looks like in the 
menu_main xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/sharebutton"
    android:title="@string/abc_shareactionprovider_share_with"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Here is the java code in MainActivity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_share) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Download this App!. ");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In the app itself, nothing happens when I click the button on the action bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have omitted startActivity(sendIntent);

```
if (id == R.id.action_share) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Download this App!. ");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
    return true;
}
```